# Microsoft Word VSTO Addin - Replacing bookmarks without deleting them

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I am working on a Word 2010 addin for a word template we are using. I have several bookmarks in the page, and their content can be changed using various wizards in the addin.

I need to add images and tables to the bookmarks now - and this works fine, but deletes the bookmark immediately afterwards. I am using the following code, passing in the bookmark.Range as a parameter.

Adding a table:

```
bookmark.Range.Tables.Add(bookmark.Range, rowCount, columnCount, ref _objectMissing, ref _objectMissing);
```

Adding an image:

```
InlineShape shape = bookmark.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path, ref _objectMissing, ref _objectMissing, ref _objectMissing);
```

I need to be able to do this without deleting the bookmark, so that I can go back and replace the image if the user runs the wizard again. Any ideas how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both InlineShape and Table objects have a Range property that you can use to restore the bookmark, like this:

```
// Keep the name of the bookmark
string bookmarkName = bookmark.Name;
// Insert your image, as before
InlineShape shape = bookmark.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path, ref _objectMissing, ref _objectMissing, ref _objectMissing);
// Restore the bookmark
Object range = shape.Range;
yourDocumentVariable.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, ref range);
```

Comment: If you get a chance - could you look at this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063832/microsoft-word-vsto-addin-inserting-multiple-tables-inside-a-text-frame